# configure voice mail after ringing state in android

Tags: android

Please help me, i'm new in Android how to set voice mail after ringing state in android app.i tried on ringing and hookoff and idle state but i'm not able to code of set voice mail configuration after the ringing state.

Please tell me, where i can call this voice mail feature in the application.?

My App. code is shown below.:

```
   public boolean wasRinging = false;@
   Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
           if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
               state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
               if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                   inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                   wasRinging = true;
                   ringing = true;
                   Date dt = new Date();
                   int hours = dt.getHours();
                   int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
                   int seconds = dt.getSeconds();
                   String curTime = hours + "" + minutes + "" + seconds;
                   //Toast.makeText(context," "+curTime,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   int mTime = Integer.parseInt(mrng.toString());
                   int eTime = Integer.parseInt(evng.toString());
                   int currentTime = Integer.parseInt(curTime.toString());
                   if (currentTime < mTime && currentTime > eTime) {
                       //workinhrs=true;
                       String work = "no";
                       Toast.makeText(context, " " + work, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   } else {
                       String work = "yes";
                       Toast.makeText(context, " " + work, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }
                   TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                   int simState = telephonyManager.getSimState();
                   switch (simState) {
                   case (TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY):
                       {
                           // Get the name of the SIM operator
                           String simOperatorName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
                           //get agent phune number
                           String lineNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
                           // Toast.makeText(context,"name : "+simOperatorName+ "number : " + lineNumber , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   }
                   String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                   // Toast.makeText(context, "IN : " + inCall+ " : "+ out, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   //ion class call the url Api ang get the values fron the server.
                   //"http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors" is dummy Link used to check the Application.
                   /* Ion.with(context)
                            .load("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors")
                            .asJsonObject()
                            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                                    // do stuff with the result or error
                                    Log.i("Tag", "onCompleted" + result);
                                }
                            });*/
                   //  Toast.makeText(context, "IN JSON ION URl ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                   if (wasRinging == true) {
                       // calldisconnect=true;
                       if (ringing) {
                           if (ringing == true && callrecived == true) {
                               String RCall = "Recived";
                               Toast.makeText(context, " " + RCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }
                       }
                       Toast.makeText(context, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                       // String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                       File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/TestRecordingDasa1");
                       if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                           sampleDir.mkdirs();
                       }
                       String file_name = inCall;
                       try {
                           audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr", sampleDir);
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                       recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                       recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
                       recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                       recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                       recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
                       try {
                           recorder.prepare();
                       } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       } catch (IOException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       recorder.start();
                       recordstarted = true;
                       Toast.makeText(context, "Recording Started ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       callrecived = true;
                       /* if(callrecived){
                        callrecived=true;
                        Log.d("call rec", "call recived true...................................");}*/
                   }
               } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                   wasRinging = false;
                   callidle = true;
                   calldisconnect = false;
                   if (ringing) {
                       if (ringing == true && callrecived == true) {
                           String mCall = "cal ended";
                           Toast.makeText(context, " " + mCall, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       } else {
                           String mCall = "missed call ";
                           Toast.makeText(context, " " + mCall, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   }
                   // Toast.makeText(context, "REJECT || DISCO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   if (recordstarted) {
                       recorder.stop();
                       recordstarted = false;
                   }
                   //end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                   long total_time = start_time;
                   //long second= ((total_time/1000)%60);
                   long second = ((total_time) / 60000) % 60;
                   // long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(total_time);
                   Toast.makeText(context, "Call Duration: " + second, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Ion.with(context)
                       .load("http://microblogging.wingnity.com/JSONParsingTutorial/jsonActors")
                       .asJsonObject()
                       .setCallback(new FutureCallback < JsonObject > () {@
                           Override
                           public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                               // do stuff with the result or error
                               Log.i("Tag...........", "onCompleted.............." + result);
                           }
                       });
                   // Toast.makeText(context, "IN JSON ION URl Call Rejected ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               } else if (state.equals(Call.STATE_DISCONNECTED)) {
                   wasRinging = true;
                   // calldisconnect=false;
                   if (ringing) {
                       if (ringing == true && callrecived == true && callidle == false) {
                           String dCall = "call disconnected";
                           Toast.makeText(context, " " + dCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
           if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
               outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
               Toast.makeText(context, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Please try to narrow down your example so that it contains only the relevant code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)